# Выбор слов из массива с таким же порядком букв

Tags: php

Как можно выводить список подходящих слов, если у вводимого изначально неизвестны все буквы? Допустим, если я введу слово `уд**ка`, то нужно чтобы с массива самых разных слов, вывелись только те, у которых на этих же местах стоят такие же буквы, в данном случае`удочка` и `удавка`. Я понимаю, что их можно сравнивать посимвольно, но это когда 2 строки известно, а когда часть одной из строк дана не полностью, то я получается звездочки приравниваются к ошибке, когда на одной позиции разные буквы.

Comment: генерите regex `/^уд..ка$/u` и примеряйте  например с помощью preg_grep

Comment: @splash58, то что нужно, спасибо